# What is the is the difference between object and data link for while creating materials?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

What is the difference between the two options provided when creating a material while using the blender render engine?

heres an image.

[image]

Comment: related answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32665/2217

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Borrowed from iKIsR from [different question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/614/7777):

> Linking a material to Data (to mesh specific data) is ideal when you want a mesh to always have the same material, while linking a material to an object is when you want to have different materials on objects that share the same mesh.
>
> Short explanation: If connected to the object, you can have several instances of the same Data using different materials. If linked to mesh data, you can't.

Comment: You [should](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) add the link back to iklsr's answer.