# Get object segmentation from render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm trying to use blender with cycles to render various synthetic block scenes, but I'd like to get for each pixel in the output image the object that is at that pixel. Ultimately this would give me an object segmentation of my scene. Is this possible with cycles?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What are synthetic blocks? Which output image? Can you add more information, or reference images, or screenshots of your goals, etc

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28557/problem-with-casting-rays-from-the-camera-into-the-scene-for-each-pixel  and somewhat related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48960/render-pass-that-output-center-of-object-of-each-pixel